# Encode videos using Nodejs + ffmpeg or handbrake

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, handbrake

I have been looking for a way to encode multiple videos simultaneously from NodeJS but I haven't find a good solution for it yet.

Using FFMPEG I never get a 100% fail free response. There is always a broken video.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

```
size = "#{options.maxWidth}x#{options.maxHeight}"
proc = new ffmpeg({
        source: options.input
      }).withVideoCodec(options.encoder).withSize(size).keepPixelAspect(true).withStrictExperimental()
proc.onProgress (progress) ->
  console.log "progress: " + progress.percent

proc.saveToFile options.output, (stdout, stderr) ->
  console.log "file has been converted succesfully"
```

Comment: FFmpeg is by far the most reliable way to encode video.  If you're getting broken videos, something is wrong.  I don't know what module you're using to interface with FFmpeg, but I suggest trying a different one.  I also suggest telling us exactly what the errors are that you're getting, and show the full FFmpeg command (assuming this module isn't binding directly to the libraries).

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [handbrake-js](https://github.com/75lb/handbrake-js)?

An example encode:

```
const hbjs = require('handbrake-js')

hbjs.spawn({ input: 'video.avi', output: 'video.m4v' })
  .on('progress', progress => {
    const { percentComplete, eta } = progress
    console.log(`Percent complete: ${percentComplete}, ETA: ${eta}`
  })
```

Comment: Handbreak also cause issue with certain video clips.